# font-size of items in a gcheckboxgroup in gWidgets2

Tags: gwidgets

I want to increase the font-size of the items appearing in a gcheckboxgroup in gWidgets2. size()<- and font()<- do not seem to offer a solution.

Comment: Sorry, no such support. For RGtk2, I just added the method to the github master of `gWidgets2RGtk2`. Otherwise, you could copy the code, which basically does this: `sapply(widget$widgets, function(bg) widget$set_rgtk2_font(bg$child, value))` where `widget` is the widget and `value` the font specification.

Comment: Wow! It worked- many thanks John.